# Yosemite when logged in will not connect to internet (but during system recovery mode will)

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, macos, internet

Upgraded to Yosemite over the weekend and before the upgrade had I no issues with internet connectivity. After upgrading I noticed that I was unable to connect to the internet at home, but presumed it was a random issue and switched it off. On bringing my MacBook into my work I noticed that it would also not connect to the internet connection in work ether via both WiFi and cabled connections, though I could still connect to LAN devices.

The odd thing is that when using the System Recovery screen the internet connection appears to work fine as it was downloading the Yosemite image to reinstall it (though this kept failing because of too many people attempting to download the new release so was unable to attempt a reinstall) which makes me think its more of an issue something added to the recent OS upgrade.

Does anyone else have this issue, or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue by clean installing the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Turned off "Automatic proxy discovery" on home network with double firewalls and no proxy. Now the internet is back.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine had this happening to him after he upgraded to Mavericks. I managed to fix it by going to 'Network Preferences', then for the desired network open go to TCP/IP, and then choose 'Renew DHCP lease'.

He had to do this for every network that his computer previously knew, but only once.

Comment: Already tried this and it unfortunately didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I installed Yosemite under a non-admin profile on my iMac. I went into the Admin profile and made the profile I installed Yosemite under an admin as well. That seems to have fixed my connectivity issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

I also installed Yosemite from a user profile. I switched to the admin profile and if fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the discoveryd service by unloading and reloading it is what ended up working for me. [Found on this article](http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/25/fix-wi-fi-problems-os-x-yosemite/).

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist

sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist
```